# Using django-compressor does not compress js

Tags: django, wagtail, django-compressor

I can't for the life of me get compress js to work, compress css works fine.

Rather than double post the entire thing, I've added a github issue here with all the details.

https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/858

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: By any chance do you have `COMPRESS_OFFLINE=True` in settings? Didn't see it in the settings, just confirming. Have you tried compressing using command e.g. `./manage.py compress --force` does it work that way? If not try to remove `manifest.json` from `STATIC_ROOT/CACHE/` and repeat.

Comment: Hi Aamir.  compress_offline wasn't on, and running the compress --force command created the manifest file in the right place, and the css folder and it's files, but no js folder, so no js files, and no error

Answer (score 1):

What a doughnut!!

I tried changing the name of the test js file being called in after a tip from Aamir, and it failed, ok, good.

So I went and had a look at the file in question, and it was bloody empty!!

Moron

Ok, works fine, exactly as stated on the tin.

Thanks